# Can't read file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Here is my method which reads content of file. Unfortunately doesn't work for me. The path to file is correct. What I miss ?

```
- (IBAction)readFile:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/joe/text.txt" 
                      encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding 
                      error:nil
                    ];
    NSLog(@"%@", str); //Result is null

}
```

Comment: Isn't there an NSPath class ? Hm..

Comment: I wonder what that error parameter to stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: is for?

Comment: @Legolas, what you mean about NSPath
JosephH I'm not sure.

Comment: @user979009: What JosephH means is you should pass a value to the error parameter, and actually check what the error was when trying to read the file. (Or rather, not an error but an address reference.)

Comment: @Inerdia I get it ! Thanks ! The problem was at encoding param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the built-in functionality of `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` and give it a `NSError` and you can see exactly whats wrong:

```
- (IBAction)readFile:(id)sender {
    NSError *readFileError = nil;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/joe/text.txt" 
                      encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding 
                      error:&readFileError
                    ];
    if (readFileError) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [readFileError localizedDescription], [readFileError localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }
}
```